# What are all the "music genres" ending with core? (which are related to nightcore)

Tags: meaning, genre, electronic-music, style, playlists

I already know of nightcore, daycore, cottagecore, and slowcore but I believe there are more and I want to be able to listen to them all. Unfortunately, I don't know how exactly to research this and my results have been off by a long shot so I need help on an entire list (least explicit to most if you can,) thank you.